# "gulp serve" is returning workbench.html that i can not add the web part to

Tags: node.js, gulp, nvm, spfx

I have developed an SPFx web part with this details:-

yo-rc.json for the project, is:-

```
{
  "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": {
    "isCreatingSolution": true,
    "environment": "spo",
    "version": "1.12.1",
    "libraryName": "spfx-my-modal-popup",
    "libraryId": "616c9b54-d123-42d8-9942-9abb0fe4f46c",
    "packageManager": "npm",
    "isDomainIsolated": false,
    "componentType": "webpart"
  }
}
```

now i installed nvm to be able to run multiple node versions, here what i did so far:-

1- I install node version 10.24.1 , then i use it as follow :-

```
nvm use 10.24.1
```

2- i run :-

```
gulp serve
```

The `https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html` opened but when i tried to add the web part by clicking on the + icon i will get this error inside the F12 developer tool:-

here is the full error:-

```
[1636842661379][PropertyPaneLoader] [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:

***Failed to load component "f9e737b7-f0df-4597-ba8c-3060f82380db" (SPPropertyPane). Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-property-pane/dist/dist/sp-property-pane_en-us.js' for resource 'sp-property-pane' in component 'f9e737b7-f0df-4597-ba8c-3060f82380db' (SPPropertyPane). The file was not found in the server. Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve'.



***INNERERROR:

***Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-property-pane/dist/dist/sp-property-pane_en-us.js' for resource 'sp-property-pane' in component 'f9e737b7-f0df-4597-ba8c-3060f82380db' (SPPropertyPane). The file was not found in the server. Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve'.

***CALLSTACK:

SPError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:24443:24
SPLoaderError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:42161:28
ff4n/ErrorBuilder</ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46155:21
ff4n/ErrorBuilder</ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46024:21
_loadComponentImpl/<@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45362:75
promise callback*_loadComponentImpl@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45361:8
_loadComponentRetryStrategy@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45299:12
_loadComponentRetryStrategy/<@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45309:20
promise callback*_loadComponentRetryStrategy@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45304:10
_loadComponentRetryStrategy/<@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45309:20
promise callback*_loadComponentRetryStrategy@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45304:10
loadComponent@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45281:55
++S4/SPRequireJsComponentLoader</SPRequireJsComponentLoader.prototype._loadComponentWithExecutor@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:41771:85
td2X/LoadComponentExecutor</LoadComponentExecutor.prototype.loadComponent@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46896:21
++S4/SPRequireJsComponentLoader</SPRequireJsComponentLoader.prototype.loadComponent@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:41742:44
Uk6p/BaseComponentLoader</BaseComponentLoader.prototype.loadComponentById@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:44816:25
KZU3/SPComponentLoader</SPComponentLoader.loadComponentById@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:43438:44
get@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:110639:99
set@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:16957:21
set@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:14989:13
CanvasToolboxHint/_this._handleClick@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/chunk.sp-canvas-edit_7833b0118fe685da1388.js:3982:17
callCallback@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75432:14
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75482:16
invokeGuardedCallback@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75539:31
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75553:25
executeDispatch@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75844:42
executeDispatchesInOrder@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75866:20
executeDispatchesAndRelease@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75963:29
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75971:10
forEachAccumulated@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75945:8
runEventsInBatch@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:76099:21
runExtractedEventsInBatch@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:76107:19
handleTopLevel@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:80109:30
batchedUpdates$1@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:95687:12
batchedUpdates@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:77434:12
dispatchEvent@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:80188:19
interactiveUpdates$1/<@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:95738:14
unstable_runWithPriority@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:97248:12
interactiveUpdates$1@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:95737:22
sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:26401:21
Uncaught (in promise) Error: ***Failed to load component "f9e737b7-f0df-4597-ba8c-3060f82380db" (SPPropertyPane). Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-property-pane/dist/dist/sp-property-pane_en-us.js' for resource 'sp-property-pane' in component 'f9e737b7-f0df-4597-ba8c-3060f82380db' (SPPropertyPane). The file was not found in the server. Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve'.
    SPError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:24443
    SPLoaderError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:42161
    buildErrorWithVerboseLog https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46155
    buildLoadComponentError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46024
    _loadComponentImpl https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45362
    promise callback*_loadComponentImpl https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45361
    _loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45299
    _loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45309
    promise callback*_loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45304
    _loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45309
    promise callback*_loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45304
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45281
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46458
    _loadComponentImpl https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:43631
    promise callback*PypK/SystemJsFallbackLoader</SystemJsFallbackLoader.prototype._loadComponentImpl https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:43621
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46896
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:43617
    _loadComponentWithExecutor https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:41781
    promise callback*++S4/SPRequireJsComponentLoader</SPRequireJsComponentLoader.prototype._loadComponentWithExecutor https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:41777
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46896
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:41742
    loadComponentById https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:44816
    loadComponentById https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:43438
    get https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:110639
    set https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:16957
    set https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:14989
    _handleClick https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/chunk.sp-canvas-edit_7833b0118fe685da1388.js:3982
    callCallback https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75432
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75482
    invokeGuardedCallback https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75539
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75553
    executeDispatch https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75844
    executeDispatchesInOrder https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75866
    executeDispatchesAndRelease https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75963
    executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75971
    forEachAccumulated https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75945
    runEventsInBatch https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:76099
    runExtractedEventsInBatch https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:76107
    handleTopLevel https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:80109
    batchedUpdates$1 https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:95687
    batchedUpdates https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:77434
    dispatchEvent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:80188
    1 https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:95738
    unstable_runWithPriority https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:97248
    interactiveUpdates$1 https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:95737
    interactiveUpdates https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:77453
    dispatchInteractiveEvent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:80165
sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:24430:28
Uncaught (in promise) Error: ***Failed to load component "f9e737b7-f0df-4597-ba8c-3060f82380db" (SPPropertyPane). Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-property-pane/dist/dist/sp-property-pane_en-us.js' for resource 'sp-property-pane' in component 'f9e737b7-f0df-4597-ba8c-3060f82380db' (SPPropertyPane). The file was not found in the server. Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve'.
    SPError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:24443
    SPLoaderError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:42161
    buildErrorWithVerboseLog https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46155
    buildLoadComponentError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46024
    _loadComponentImpl https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45362
    promise callback*_loadComponentImpl https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45361
    _loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45299
    _loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45309
    promise callback*_loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45304
    _loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45309
    promise callback*_loadComponentRetryStrategy https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45304
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45281
    _loadComponentWithExecutor https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:41771
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46896
    loadComponent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:41742
    loadComponentById https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:44816
    loadComponentById https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:43438
    get https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:110639
    set https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:16957
    set https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:14989
    _handleClick https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/chunk.sp-canvas-edit_7833b0118fe685da1388.js:3982
    callCallback https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75432
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75482
    invokeGuardedCallback https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75539
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75553
    executeDispatch https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75844
    executeDispatchesInOrder https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75866
    executeDispatchesAndRelease https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75963
    executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75971
    forEachAccumulated https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:75945
    runEventsInBatch https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:76099
    runExtractedEventsInBatch https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:76107
    handleTopLevel https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:80109
    batchedUpdates$1 https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:95687
    batchedUpdates https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:77434
    dispatchEvent https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages
```

here is my `MyModalPopupWebPart.ts`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'MyModalPopupWebPartStrings';
import MyModalPopup from './components/MyModalPopup';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './components/IMyModalPopupProps';

export interface IMyModalPopupWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  WhoWeAre: string;
  OurValue:string;
}

export default class MyModalPopupWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyModalPopupWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> = React.createElement(
      MyModalPopup,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        WhoWeAre: this.properties.WhoWeAre,
        OurValue: this.properties.OurValue
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('WhoWeAre', {
                  label: "who We Are",
                  multiline: true
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('OurValue', {
                  label: "Our value",
                  multiline: true
                }), PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: "Description"
                }),
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

here is my `MYModal.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import { sanitize } from 'dompurify';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitize(myprops.WhoWeAre) }} />

        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};
```

here is my `MyModalPopup.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './IMyModalPopupProps';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { MYModal } from './MYModal';
import { MYModal2 } from './MYModal2';

interface IPopupState {
  showModal: string;
}

export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IMyModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IMyModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: ''
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: ''
    })
  }
  private Buttonclick(e, whichModal) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: whichModal });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> {

    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'our-value')} text="Our Value" />
        { showModal === 'our-value' && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'who-we-are')} text="Who We Are" />
        { showModal === 'who-we-are' && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your serve.json look like?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils this is `{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://localhost:5432/workbench",
  "api": {
    "port": 5432,
    "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  }
}
`

Comment: That looks good to me. But the location it's trying to find that file is wrong as the answer points out; should only be one `dist`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is double "dist" in the URL you have. You need to remove one somehow:

`.../sp-property-pane/dist/dist/sp-property-pane_en/...`

It seems to be some project misconfiguration issue. I would recommend you to create a new project, following the steps from the "getting started" official tutorial here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

Make sure you have the recommended version of node installed (there is "set up your development environment" chapter, please make sure you follow what is written there).

Comment: when i tried to create a new Hello world web part,,, and i run `gulp serve` i will get this error `Cannot GET /temp/workbench.html` .. here is the setting for my `.yo-rc`  `{
  "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": {
    "plusBeta": false,
    "isCreatingSolution": true,
    "environment": "spo",
    "version": "1.13.0",
    "libraryName": "f",
    "libraryId": "ef98ebd8-128a-4417-a2b8-d57a9f3e3df4",
    "packageManager": "npm",
    "isDomainIsolated": false,
    "componentType": "webpart"
  }
}
` any idea?

Comment: Please make sure you are using the supported NODE version and follow the tutorial. It DOES work. I would recommend you delete the .yo-rc file and start from scratch.

Comment: node version is `C:\f>node -v
v12.22.7`.. and SPFx version is `1.13.0` so both should work well together

Comment: I have not checked with 1.13.0 (it was released just recently). As far as  remember they said that they will deprecate local workbench, only remote will be supported starting with 1.13. May this be somehow related?

Comment: yes i changed the `"initialPage": "https://myrealserver.sharepoint.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx"` and the hello world is working well

Comment: so back to my question ... why my web part which have `SPFX version "version": "1.12.1",` & `node version `10.24.1` is not working when i run `gulp serve`

Comment: Can you share the full code and config (as a github repo for example)? Otherwise, it's hard to tell, really )

Comment: ok i provided the full code